# Bash: array made from inside a sourced function won't be exported

Tags: arrays, bash

Consider the following script, that just creates and prints arrays out of lists:

```
 $> cat my_script.sh
 #!/bin/sh
 function test_array {
    export list_2="ai ia"
    export list_2_array=($list_2)
    echo list_2=$list_2
    echo list_2_array=$list_2_array
 }
 export list="oi io"
 export list_array=($list)
 echo list=$list
 echo list_array=$list_array
 test_array
```

Sourcing the script, will yield correct values for the set variables and arrays:

```
 $> . my_script.sh
 list=oi io
 list_array=oi
 list_2=ai ia
 list_2_array=ai
```

Running the function inside the script will still yield correct values for them:

```
 $> test_array
 list_2=ai ia
 list_2_array=ai
```

However, whilst `list_2` is properly set, `list_2_array` is nowhere:

```
 $> echo list_2=$list_2
 list_2=ai ia

 $> echo list_2_array=$list_2_array
 list_2_array=
```

I checked the autocompletion and, indeed, `list_2_array` is not even set.

What's the rationale behind this behaviour?

Comment: I have found a bug related to sourced scripts and arrays: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2014-05/msg00045.html . Although it doesn't look the same issue, it suggests me that this may be actually a bug. My bash version is 4.1.2(1).

Comment: running `env` will definitively tell you if the variable is there

Comment: maybe you need `#!/bin/bash` at the top? Good luck.

Comment: The environment is an array of strings. I think it should be fundamentally impossible to export a nonstring data structure regardless of the context.

Answer (score 0):

The `readonly` builtin has the same problem:

```
bash-4.4$ foo() { readonly a=(1);echo a=$a; }
bash-4.4$ foo
a=1
bash-4.4$ echo a=$a
a=
```

May be this is a bug, so I suggest you report this to bug-bash with the title "An array variable created by export/readonly builtins inside a function becomes a locale variable to that function unexpectedly".